# Can't find better solution with loops

Tags: powershell, loops

I have a task in PowerShell that checks the name of the file and if it exists add number at the end and if it exists after first check we will increase number by one.

I have trouble with increasing number by 1.

```
$path = 'D:\Test\TestFile.zip'

if (Test-Path $path) {
    # File exists, append number
    $fileSeed = 0
    do {
        $path = $path  -replace ".zip$"
        $path += ''
        $fileSeed++
        $path = "$path$fileSeed.zip"
    } until ( ! (Test-Path $path) )
} else {
    $path
}
```

Comment: If it comes the the loop second time, it will add new number at the end, but not increase the first one

Comment: if you want a very simple-minded solution ... don't use sequential numbers. [*grin*] instead use a timestamp added to the end of the file name. that can get as granular as needed AND it lets you still get a sequence that shows the "newest" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago, I've written a small function for that called `Get-UniqueFileName`.

```
function Get-UniqueFileName {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path
    )

    $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($Path)
    $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path)    # this includes the dot
    # get an array of all files with the same extension currently in the directory
    $allFiles  = @(Get-ChildItem $directory -File -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

    # construct the possible new file name (just the name, not hte full path and name)
    $newFile = $baseName + $extension
    $seed = 1
    while ($allFiles -contains $newFile) {
        # add the seed value between brackets. (you can ofcourse leave them out if you like)
        $newFile = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $baseName, $seed, $extension
        $seed++
    }
    # return the full path and filename
    return Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath $newFile
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Get-UniqueFileName -Path 'D:\Test\TestFile.zip'
```

If directory `D:\Test` already contained a file named `TestFile.zip` and another file named `TestFile(1).zip`, it will return `D:\Test\TestFile(2).zip`

Comment: Thanks a lot!) it helps me